# How to create sub columns under a super column in a column family

Tags: java, cassandra, super

I am looking for a procedure to create to a sub column list under a super column.
The column family structure should look like

```
ColumnFamilyName{
     row_key: #something 
     Column:{
                Col1: {Name: "#text", value:"#value"},
                Col2: {Name: "#text", value:"#value", Name1: "#text", value:"#value"}
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really a notion of "creating" a super column. Once you insert any subcolumns with that supercolumn name, the supercolumn exists.  Likewise, a supercolumn cannot exist without any subcolumns.

The [pycassa docs on super column usage](http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/assorted/super_columns.html) might be helpful to look at.  In short, your insert will look something like this:

```py
col_fam.insert('row_key', {'supercol_name': {'col_name': 'col_val'}})
```

However, at this point, using super columns is **not** recommended.  Composite columns should be used instead in just about every case.